# dynamic linear model regression using dlmModReg() and dlmForecast() in R

Tags: r

I am doing a dynamic linear regression analysis, but always encounter the errorn as shown example:

```
nAhead <- 12
mod <- dlmModSeas(4)+dlmModReg(cbind(rnorm(100+nAhead),rnorm(100+nAhead)))
fi <- dlmFilter(c(rnorm(100),rep(NA,nAhead)),mod)
f <- dlmForecast(fi,nAhead=12)
```

Error in dlmForecast(fi, nAhead = 12) : 
  dlmForecast only works with constant models

How to use dlmForecast() correctly?